# geom_image from ggimage arbitrarily selects aspect ratio

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggimage

I am trying to insert a logo in my plot using `geom_image()`. The original logo is available here:
https://www.itvoice.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/zebronics_footer_logo.png 
and looks like this:
[image]

When I make a ggplot using the code below, I get this image where the logo is shrunk along the x axis.

[image]

When I used `reprex` to make this post, the resulting logo was shrunk along Y axis. Neither of them is the correct rendition. I can't figure out what's going on here. I tried to play around with various parameters such as `size` and `asp` but I can't reproduce the original logo correctly.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggimage)

df <- data.frame(imglink = "https://www.itvoice.in/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/zebronics_footer_logo.png",
                 x = 1,
                 y = 1)

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, image = imglink)) +
  geom_image(size = 0.5) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

This issue got resolved after I installed development versions of `ggimage` and `ggplot2` and restarted RStudio.

Comment: The issue does not get resolved for me after installing the development version with `devtools::install_github("GuangchuangYu/ggimage")`